# How to I make a temporary filename that's safe for concurrent execution?

Tags: c, linux, temporary-files

In the following code, I need a unique filename, do some stuff with it, and let it be. It is about converting a .class file to binary, let us call it compilation.

It works perfectly when run in isolation or done 3 times at a time; however, I run into issues when I start up many multiple processes (e.g., 7) where one or more of my compilations fail.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static unsigned int numFiles = 0;
static unsigned long numBytes = 0;

FILE* rawf;
char* raw_file_name_end = ".raw_ujc";
char * rawfilename;

static void byte(unsigned char v){
    if(numBytes) printf(", ");

    printf((numBytes & 0x0F) ? "0x%02X" : "\n\t0x%02X", v);

    fwrite(&v,sizeof(v),1,rawf);

    numBytes++;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    const char* self = argv[0];
    int c;
    const char* classCvt = 0;
    long len;

    if(argc == 1){

        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s [-c <path_to_classCvt>] <file 1> [<file 2> [ <file 3> [...]]] > result.c\n", self);
        return -1;
    }

    argv++;
    argc--;

    if(argv[0][0] == '-' && argv[0][1] == 'c' && !argv[0][2]){

        classCvt = argv[1];
        argv += 2;
        argc -= 2;
    }

    printf("\nService optimized bytecode = {\n\t");

    while(argc--){
        char* filename = *argv;

        rawfilename = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(filename)-strlen(".class")) + sizeof(char) * strlen(raw_file_name_end)+1);

        strncpy(rawfilename,filename,(strlen(filename)-strlen(".class")));
        strcat(rawfilename,raw_file_name_end);
        fprintf(stderr, "rawfilename after alloc: %s \n", rawfilename);

        if(classCvt){

            char* t;

            filename = tempnam(NULL, NULL);
            if(!filename){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to create a tempfile: %d\n", self, errno);
                return -10;
            }

            t = malloc(strlen(filename) + strlen(classCvt) + strlen(*argv) + 32);
            if(!t){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to alloc a small string. This is unlikely\n", self);
                free(t);
                return -11;
            }
            sprintf(t, "%s < %s > %s", classCvt, *argv, filename);

            if(system(t)){

                fprintf(stderr, "%s: system() fail: %d\n", self, errno);
                free(t);
                return -12;
            }
            free(t);
        }
        printf("filename is %s\n",filename);
        FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
        rawf = fopen(rawfilename, "wb");


        if(filename != *argv){
            unlink(filename);
            free(filename);
        }

        if(!f){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -2;
        }
        if(!f){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -2;
        }
        if(fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END)){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to seek(1) in '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -3;
        }
        len = ftell(f);
        if(len < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to tell in '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -4;
        }
        if(fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to seek(2) in '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -5;
        }
        if(len > 0x00FFFFFFUL){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:  file '%s' is %lu bytes, while maximum allowable size is %lu.\n", self, *argv, len, 0x00FFFFFFUL);
            fclose(f);
            return -6;
        }

        byte(len >> 16);
        byte(len >> 8);
        byte(len);

        while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
            byte(c);
        }

        numFiles++;
        fclose(f);
        fclose(rawf);

        argv++;
    }

    byte(0);
    byte(0);
    byte(0);

    printf("\n};\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: processed %u files, producing %lu (0x%lX) bytes of output\n", self, numFiles, numBytes, numBytes);
    fprintf(stderr, "rawfilename at end: %s \n", rawfilename);
    free(rawfilename);

    return 0;
}
```

After looking around, people recommend using `mkstemp()`; however, as you can see, I actually do need the filename in several places.

I tried adjusting this but keep running into errors. How can I safely adjust this work method?

Comment: Please be more specific on which kind of issues you are actually run in.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  In particular, it's considered impolite to bury such calls to `system()` in code that others might want to try out when investigating your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manpage for `mkstemp`

```
int mkstemp(char *template);
```

> The mkstemp() function generates a unique temporary filename from template, creates and opens the file, and returns an open file descriptor for the file.
>          The last six characters of template must be "XXXXXX" and these are
>          replaced with a string that makes the filename unique.  **Since it will
>          be modified, template must not be a string constant, but should be
>          declared as a character array.**
>          The file is created with permissions 0600, that is, read plus write
>          for owner only.  The returned file descriptor provides both read and
>          write access to the file.  The file is opened with the open(2) O_EXCL
>          flag, guaranteeing that the caller is the process that creates the
>          file.

so if you need the filename, you can find it in the `template` argument passed to mkstemp.